# Not Working Laravel Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am Try to get data in `many to many` relationship and its show a `NULL` value and i am use `php artisan tinker` to check my many to many relationship also its show `Null` Value

this is my `TenderMaster` Model

```
  class TenderMaster extends Model
    {
      protected $table = 'hmcs_tender';
      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $primarykey = 'id';


    public function Ports()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Masters\Air\AirPortCode','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','bid_id','port_id');
    }
    }
```

This is my `AirPortCode` Model

```
class AirPortCode extends Model
{
 Protected $table = 'hmsc_air_port_codes';
 public $timestamps = false;
 Protected $primaryKey = 'id';

 public function Tenders()
 {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Admin_Module\TenderMaster','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','port_id','bid_id');
 }
}
```

This is my Blade.php  i use to this method to get data in to many to many relationship `{{$tenders->Ports['port_id']}}`

```
 @foreach($tender as $key => $tenders)


                                    <tbody>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->bid_name}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->bid_name}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->bid_year}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->shipping_mode}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->start_date}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->Ports['port_id']}}</td>
                                     <td>{{$tenders->bid_name}}</td>
                                     <td style="text-align:center">
                                     <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">View</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Send</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Quotation</button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>

                                     </td>
                                    </tbody>
                                    @endforeach
```

this is my table. table name is `hmsc_tender` primary key is `id`
[image]

this is my `many to many` relationship join table table name is `hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm`
[image]

Comment: Show your database table field as well.?

Comment: sure i will post it now my table

Comment: sure i will post db also

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 public function Ports()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Masters\Air\AirPortCode','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','port_id','bid_id');
    }
```

and

```
public function Tenders()
 {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Admin_Module\TenderMaster','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','bid_id','port_id');
 }
```

Comment: there is a no deference this two functions are 100% same to my code ..!! first see my code bro

Comment: i switch "port_id" and "bid_id"  in both functions !